# PHP Talking with Exchange getting SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, exchangewebservices

Im trying to communicate with Exchange using SOAP. But i have got a popular problem.

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://123.456.78.9:444/EWS/Services.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://123.456.78.9:444/EWS/Services.wsdl"

There is nothing wrong with the url, because it can be opened in browser.
I know, this question has been asked many time, but I still get no correct answer. I really appreciate your help.

And here is my little code.

```
  try {
        ini_set('display_errors', true);        //does not help
        ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");//does not help
        error_reporting(E_ALL);                 //does not help
         $client = new SoapClient(URL_EXCHANGE, array(
          "login" => USER_EXCHANGE,
          "password" => PASS_EXCHANGE)
          );        
        return $client;
    } catch (\SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
```